# Capacitor and Inductor Filters, no resistor?

Tags: transformer, mains

Often in circuit diagrams capacitors and inductors are used to either pass or attenuate high or low frequency signals. For example a choke is an inductor which can be used to limit the passage of high frequency signals and sometimes bypass capacitors will be used to "short" or "shunt" high frequency signals to ground. Sometimes such elements appear seemingly "by themselves". I understand that inductors present high impedance and high frequency and low impedance and low frequency and the opposite for capacitors so I have an intuitive sense how they can be used as high and low pass filters. However, if I want to get more quantitative I might want to know what constitutes "high frequency" or "low frequency" for a given configuration. For that there need to more details. Single pole filter cutoff frequency always involve a resistance.

For example, I'll look at capacitors or inductors chosen for circuits and wonder "why was that value for the capacitor or inductor chosen?" In my mind it must have been so that the filter has the appropriate cutoff. But what sets the resistance to determine the cutoff?

My main guess based on some recent reading I've done is that these elements (inductors or capacitors) have some amount of inductance and capacitance as they are specced, but they also have stray inductance and capacitance as well as some stray resistance. It is all of these stray features which set the ultimate technical limit for the use of some device as a filter. In that case, you would have to look at the data sheet for whichever choke or capacitor or whatever that you are using and ensure that it has the appropriate frequency response in whatever band you are concerned about. Is this correct?

The other possibility is that the resistance must come from the rest of the circuit. For example, maybe the input or output impedance of neighboring devices must be considered in series or parallel with the capacitor or inductor to determine the cutoff frequency. Or maybe it's just the resistance of the wires. I'm not sure, maybe it can be any of these.

I realize it is probably hard to give an answer to this question without me presenting a specific circuit that has confused but perhaps someone can give me some general direction anyways.

Comment: You are analyzing the issue to death! Please clean up your wall of text and remove idle thoughts and suppositions, and end questions with a '?'.

Comment: I take it you are discussing passive-only filtering? Not active? Also, you are aware that a filter also needs an impedance to it so that the circuit driving it isn't over-loaded and so that the filter also takes into account its own load?

Comment: @jonk. I think OP is getting precision filtering mixed up with a plain-jane crowbar filter. Op did not mention a cut-off point.

Comment: I think it would help if you presented a single example and made your question about that specific example. Otherwise, to answer your question, someone has to write a textbook on filtering techniques.

Comment: One basic precept of filters is that you usually do not want to attenuate the signal of interest. Another basic precept is that you must greatly attenuate any frequency content at or above Fs/2 (half the sample rate) of the ADC which is digitizing the signal.

Comment: `I'm not sure, maybe it can be any of these.` That makes these questions beyond our scope to answer (too broad). Please narrow things to a specific question, else risk having this closed.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will try to work on asking my questions in a more clear way. Perhaps the real answer is that I do in fact need to pick up a textbook on filtering techniques.

Comment: Compute the resonant frequency of the L and C used. Below that is low. As a starting point to think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The other possibility is that the resistance must come from the rest of the circuit. For example, maybe the input or output impedance of neighboring devices must be considered in series or parallel with the capacitor or inductor to determine the cutoff frequency.

Yes

For instance, see [wikipedia second order filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Second_order). The load resistor is an essential part of the transfer function.

LC filters are usually designed between finite resistance on both input and output, but can be designed to have finite resistance on only one port, with a short or open circuit on the other.

The resistance on the port is such an essential part of the design, that if the resistance changes, the filter transfer function changes. When you do finally pick up a book on filter design, you'll see that prototype filters are usually designed for a normalised '1 ohm system', and the final step of filter design is to scale all the components into the actual impedance you're using. 50 ohms and 75 ohms are popular impedances for RF filters, 600 ohms for audio and telephony.

Comment: This. And here's the book... https://www.amazon.co.uk/Handbook-Filter-Synthesis-Anatol-Zverev/dp/0471749427

Comment: More than that, LC filters should be embedded between two resistors because - in this case only - the filter provides optimum sensitivity properties (smallest influence of tolerances on transfer function).

Comment: Ah yes, Zverev. I prefer Authur B Williams, a bit more readable.

Answer (score 2):

As a guideline ... note that any frequency con be expressed as an L-C product (via the usual formula), but that tells you nothing about choosing either L or C - only their product.

Also note that the desired Q tells you about the ratio between L and R, or C and R.

So if you have a frequency requirement and a Q requirement, and the circuit provides an R (e.g. the source and load impedances are defined to be 50 ohms), between these, you can uniquely define the component values.

And R may be imposed by e.g. antenna properties, or chosen to be e.g. 50 ohms (fairly low) for high frequencies so that you don't end up with inconveniently small capacitances.

It gets more complex when multi-stage filters are considered, but they are often broken down into second order sections as part of the synthesis process.